# How are ratings determined?

Tags: audience-measurement

Once upon a long time ago, the Nielson Ratings were determined by set top box. They were pretty decently accurate, or at least accepted as so by the big three original networks. Now that there are eleventy hundred channels to watch, how are ratings determined?

Comment: It's not just the number of channels, it's our changing viewing habits, too. Tivo, streaming, and other forms of "delayed viewing."

Comment: Related (if not even perfect duplicate): http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8758/49.

Comment: Nope, that's a perfect dupe, I will accept as closing this one. I didn't find it when I looked, sorry.